# Processing FOP with parameters

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, xslt

HI,
I want to use FOP to prepare a XML document for printing (ps/pdf). 
Is it possible to send parameters to FOP to do conditional formating as exist in xsl processors

XSL:

```
<xsl:param name="isDuplicate">no</xsl:param>
....
<xsl:if test="$isDuplicate='yes'">
    <h2 align="center">Copy</h2>
</xsl:if>
....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using the fop batch/shell file that comes with the distribution, you can use the `--param` argument to fop, as d[ocumented on the Fop page](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/running.html)

```
  -param name value <value> to use for parameter <name> in xslt stylesheet
                    (repeat '-param name value' for each parameter)
```