# Apache FOP usage of "-param"

Tags: xml, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm working with Apache FOP v.1.0 (latest) on Windows XP and I want to use parameters. I used different parameter syntaxes, but "fop" doesn't use it. In the documentation is written: "-param name value".

Parts of my XML file:

```
<letter position="1">
```

I have in my XSLT file:

```
<xsl:param name="position"/>
<xsl:for-each select="letter[@position=$position]">
```

The following works:

```
<xsl:for-each select="letter[@position=1]">
```

And this works also:

```
<xsl:param name="position" select="1"/>
<xsl:for-each select="letter[@position=$position]">
```

So FOP just doesn't gets any input.

Commands I tried, which didn't work:

```
fop -param position 1 -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -pdf output.pdf
fop -xml data.xml -param position 1 -xsl stylesheet.xsl -pdf output.pdf
fop -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -param position 1 -pdf output.pdf
fop -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -pdf output.pdf -param position 1

fop -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -pdf output.pdf -param "position" 1
fop -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -pdf output.pdf -param position "1"
fop -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -pdf output.pdf -param "position" "1"

fop -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -param "position" 1 -pdf output.pdf
fop -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -param position "1" -pdf output.pdf
fop -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -param "position" "1" -pdf output.pdf

fop -xml data.xml -param "position" 1 -xsl stylesheet.xsl  -pdf output.pdf
fop -xml data.xml -param position "1" -xsl stylesheet.xsl -pdf output.pdf
fop -xml data.xml -param "position" "1" -xsl stylesheet.xsl -pdf output.pdf

fop -param "position" 1 -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl  -pdf output.pdf
fop -param position "1" -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -pdf output.pdf
fop -param "position" "1" -xml data.xml -xsl stylesheet.xsl -pdf output.pdf
```

I looked at [Processing FOP with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250855/processing-fop-with-parameters) but they don't give a working example.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `xsl:param` a child of `xsl:stylesheet` or do you have it in an `xsl:template`? It should be a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet`.

Here is a working example...

**XML Input** (param_test.xml)

```
<doc>
  <letter position="1">position 1</letter>
  <letter position="2">position 2</letter>
  <letter position="3">position 3</letter>
  <letter position="4">position 4</letter>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0** (param_test.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="position"/>

  <xsl:template match="/doc">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
          <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:for-each select="letter[@position=$position]">
            <fo:block>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </fo:block>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**FOP command line** (Version 1.0 on Windows XP)

```
fop -xml param_test.xml -xsl param_test.xsl -pdf param_test.pdf -param position 1
```

**PDF Output** (param_test.pdf)

[image]

Comment: I placed the parameter in the template (<xsl:template...). It works! Thanks very much.

Comment: So, now I have:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">`
`<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>`
`<xsl:param name="position"/>`
`<xsl:template match="/letter">`